# Button Not Showing On React Table

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I have some trouble. I tried to show a button on React Table for each row, but its not showing, its just show a blank column.
This is my column

```
columns = [
  
    {
        dataField: "nama_user",
        text: "Nama",
        sort: true,
        style: { overflowWrap: "break-word" }, 
        headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#2196F3' , color: 'white'}
    },
    {
        dataField: "email",
        text: "Email",
        sort: true,
        headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#2196F3' , color: 'white'}
    },
    {
        dataField: "",
        text: "Action",
        formatter: this.GetUserAction,
        headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#2196F3' , color: 'white'},
        classes: "p-1"
    }
];
```

This is the function that contain the button

```
GetUserAction = (cell, row, rowIndex, formatExtraData) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <button className="update" onClick={this.handleClickOpen}>
                    Edit
                </button>
                <button className="update" onClick={this.aktivasiUser(row)}>
                   Aktivasi
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Maybe I miss something in my code? Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found the problem. Need to put `columns` inside `render()` instead outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite unclear to me, if I am not wrong the word **Edit** is storing some value and that's what you want to display as a function right?
If yes then try enclosing that **Edit** value in curly braces, because in jsx if you want to interpret the content of some variable you have to enclose it into curly brackets {}.

**The curly braces are a special syntax to let the JSX parser know that it needs to interpret the contents in between them as JavaScript instead of a string. This process is generally referred to as "interpolation"**

Try doing something like this

[image]

**Let me Know if this works, else try to put some more code so that I can understand**

Comment: Ah no, Edit is not storing any value at all, its just plain text for the button.

Comment: @AnandaPramono okay, well bro your question is not quite clear, can you edit your post and show us full code which is important to understand